# Plot two equations in one plot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot two equations in one plot using Mathematica. However, I don't have any idea about how to go about it. I need to add this equation `(k^2 + Log[0.75])` to the plot. Then show the point where the curves meet each other.
Please help! Here is my code:

```
eqn[d_Integer?NonNegative, r_, B_, nmax_Integer?Positive] := 
Sum[Exp[-n*\[Lambda]]*(1 - r)^
 n Exp[
  n*k^2 - k^2*B (HarmonicNumber[n + d] - HarmonicNumber[d])], {n, 
 1, nmax}] == -1 + Exp[\[Lambda]]/r;
BValues = {0, 0.5, 5};

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, 
ContourPlot[
Evaluate@Table[eqn[10, 0.25, B, 100], {B, BValues}], {k, 1/20, 
 2}, {\[Lambda], -1, 3.5}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {k, Subscript[\[Lambda], r]}), 
  RotateLabel -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[N@BValues, LegendLabel -> "B ="], {.1, .6}], 
   GridLines -> {None, {0}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to Bill's answer

```
plot = Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
   ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[eqn[10, 0.25, B, 100], {B, BValues}],
    {k, 1/20, 2}, {λ, -1, 3.5}]];

lines = Cases[Normal[First[plot]], Line[line_] :> line, Infinity];

f1[x_] := Evaluate[Fit[lines[[1]], {x, x^2, x^3}, x]]
f2[x_] := Evaluate[Fit[lines[[2]], {x, x^2, x^3}, x]]
f3[x_] := Evaluate[Fit[lines[[3]], {x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]]

xvals = k /. Quiet[
    FindRoot[#[k] == k^2 + Log[0.75], {k, 1.5}] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}];

yvals = {f1[#1], f2[#2], f3[#3]} & @@ xvals;


Show[plot, Plot[k^2 + Log[0.75], {k, 0, 2}], 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Transpose[{xvals, yvals}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Show[
  Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
    ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[eqn[10,0.25,B,100],{B,BValues}],{k,1/20,2},{\[Lambda],-1,3.5}]
  ],
  Plot[k^2+Log[0.75],{k,0,2}]
]
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. this is true. How can I show the point that curves meet each other?