# plot function using Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I need plot this function using Mathematica. I plot this in Python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = np.linspace(0,2,100)
j = 2*k

def I(k, j):

    II = k*j - k**2 - np.log(0.75)
    return II

plt.plot(j , I(k,j))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working? Refer [help] on asking good questions. Stackoverflow isn't a translation service.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I dont have more information in mathematica. I plot this in python and want using mathematica to plot this. excuse me and sorry for bad quastion.

Comment: You've [plotted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75902972/plot-two-equations-in-one-plot-in-mathematica), so again, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this VERY carefully to make certain that every detail is EXACTLY correct.

```
k=Range[0,2,2/100];
j=2*k;
i[k_,j_]:=k*j-k^2-Log[0.75];
ListPlot[Transpose[{j,i[k,j]}]]
```

Check the documentation

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html